# ListView can't click Item in android

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` in my app.

I implemented `OnItemClickListener()` to open a `ContextMenu` when an item is clicked.

But, when i click a row, `Toast` does not appear.

Help Please,

My Code :

```
mySqlHelper dbHelper = new mySqlHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase dbRead = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    bulan = SpinBulan.getSelectedItemPosition();
    tahun = Integer.parseInt(ThnTransaksi.getText().toString());

    Calendar mycal = new GregorianCalendar(tahun, bulan, 1);
    hariBulan = mycal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    bulanTrans = bulan+1;

    String dapatId;
    int id_tgl , cariSampai;


    Cursor Cari_id = dbRead.rawQuery("select _id from m_transfer where tgl_transfer = '1/"+bulanTrans+"/"+tahun+"'",null);

    Cari_id.moveToFirst();

    dapatId = Cari_id.getString(0);


    id_tgl = Integer.parseInt(dapatId);

    cariSampai = id_tgl + hariBulan - 1;

    CariTgl = dbRead.rawQuery("select * from m_transfer where _id BETWEEN '"+id_tgl+"' and '"+cariSampai+"'",null);
    startManagingCursor(CariTgl);

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            Transfer.this, 
            R.layout.data_tanggal, 
            CariTgl, 
            new String[] {"tgl_transfer","stts_transfer"}, 
            new int[] {R.id.textListTanggal, R.id.textStatusTanggal});

    dataTanggal.setAdapter(adapter);

    dataTanggal.setSelected(true);
    dataTanggal.setOnItemClickListener(ke);
```

and `onItemClickListener()` :

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener ke = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "selected"+arg2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
};
```

Comment: what class are you extending ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are implementing a `custom adapter`, your inflated layout must implement `android:focusable="false"` in your elements or `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on your main layout to avoid to trigger any listener of the elements inside of the listview (which you dont want to)

Comment: @user3811450 you're welcome. please upvote all answers that helped you and close this topic.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to set **focusable="false"** property in xml file of listview item .
this may work

Answer (score 0):

you need to use OnItemSelectedListener instead of OnItemClicklistener

Answer (score 0):

in the textview of your inflator layout just add:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

and in parent layout of your inflator i.e in relative layout of inflator add:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```